# Trying to delete first string where pattern is found and leave second string intact

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which contains multiple rows of data and some are duplicates with date field at end of record. I want to be able to scan the file and keep the most current record. Here's what the data looks like:

```
00xbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20141231 <- remove this one
00vbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20150403 <- keep this one (newer date)
00dndf0ca080;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
00dbkf0ca292;jerry@easy.us.com;20141231 <-keep
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20141231 <- remove
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403 <- keep (newer date)
```

I tried various flavors and combinations of sed, awk, grep but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not sort the file based on addresses and descending time stamp? Then all you need to do is keep the first one:

```
 <infile sort -t\; -k2,2 -k3r | awk -F\; '!h[$2]++'
```

Output:

```
00dndf0ca080;betty@easy.us.com;20141231               
00dbkf0ca292;jerry@easy.us.com;20141231
00vbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20150403
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403
```

Comment: This seems to work great, Thank You very much!!  I have been trying all kinds of options to no avail..

Comment: Thor, I ran into an issue..  Seems when there are multiple entries for same person and are on same date the sort throws away the other entries and only keeps one. How can I have it keep all entries on same date for that same person and only throw away any that are the same but have older dates?  Example is below..
0026cv6v03a9;dr@ust.test.com;20150406 (keep)
0026gvgv03a7;dr@ust.test.com;20150406 (keep)
0026gvgv03a7;dr@ust.test.com;20140403 (throw away, same as previous record but older date)
0026wv6w03a7;dr@ust.test.com;20150406 (keep)
0026wv6w03a7;dr@ust.test.com;20140403 <- throw away

Comment: @dr057: This radically changes the solution. I think you should post this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  split($0,parts,/;/)
  if (link[parts[2]] < parts[3]) {
    link[parts[2]] = parts[3]
  }
}

END {
  for (l in link) {
    print l,link[l]
  }
}
```

produces:

```
sue@easy.us.com 20141231
jerry@easy.us.com 20141231
joe@easy.us.com 20150403
betty@easy.us.com 20141231
john@easy.us.com 20150403
```

Comment: Thx, but is there a way to keep it in same format and include the fist string
00xbdf0c9fd6; ?

so it would come out like this:

00vbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20150403 
00dndf0ca080;betty@easy.us.com;20141231  
00dbkf0ca292;jerry@easy.us.com;20141231  
0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403
00dbdq0ca459;sue@easy.us.com;20141231

Comment: Like this so there's one string on each row..

00vbdf0c9fd6;joe@easy.us.com;20150403 
00dndf0ca080;betty@easy.us.com;20141231 00dbkf0ca292;jerry@easy.us.com;20141231 0dbds0ca2f6;john@easy.us.com;20150403 00dbdq0ca459;sue@easy.us.com;20141231